How to fix this error on Electrum personal server?
I try to setup Electrum Personal Server between my Bitcoin code node and electrum wallet on Mac OS.
I configured files as found in various tutorials, and when I launch EPS I have these messages :
INFO:2024-12-23 18:10:15,987: Starting Electrum Personal Server 0.2.4
INFO:2024-12-23 18:10:15,987: Logging to /var/folders/6j/hmnxd9w94zn1s4zd35gz35km0000gn/T/electrumpersonalserver.log
INFO:2024-12-23 18:10:15,993: Displaying first 3 addresses of each master public key:
INFO:2024-12-23 18:10:15,996: 
default_wallet =>
    1Q6HK8akN2Bex1Vw6eXeSa575czMUkmGRr
    1QCGbjW5z9bRLJwoYj6edHV1W1AWhnjHSs
    19KSfRYaeBJvtnFs2JovHxrqsJ5fDzB2gH
INFO:2024-12-23 18:10:15,997: Obtaining bitcoin addresses to monitor . . .
INFO:2024-12-23 18:10:15,997: Importing 1 wallets and 0 watch-only addresses into the Bitcoin node

But after a few seconds, I have this error:
electrumpersonalserver.server.jsonrpc.JsonRpcError: {'code': -4, 'message': 'Only legacy wallets are supported by this command'}

It's weird as the wallet seems legacy, the displayed addresses are correct compared to electrum wallet, and they begin with 1.
I also created new certificates as it was mentioned on another post but the problem is the same.
As anyone encountered this problem and could help me to figure it out ?
Thanks :)
